# Differential Forms Taking Vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ be differential $p$-form and $q$-form, respectively. Given $p+q$ vector fields $X_1, X_2, \dots X_{p+q}$, I am wondering that if there is a relation between $\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 (X_1, \dots, X_{p+q})$ and some product of $\omega_1(X_{i_1}, \dots, X_{i_p})$ and $\omega_2(X_{i_{p+1}}, \dots, X_{i_{p+q}})$? For example, if $p = q =1$, we have simply
\begin{eqnarray}
\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 (X_1, X_2)=
\begin{vmatrix}
\omega_1(X_1) && \omega_1(X_2) \\
\omega_2(X_1) && \omega_2(X_2)
\end{vmatrix}.
\end{eqnarray}

I have also tried the case $p = n, q = 1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, in which I get
\begin{eqnarray}
\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 (X_1, \dots, X_{n+1}) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k+1} \omega_1(X_1, \dots, \hat{X}_k, \dots, X_{n+1}) \omega_2(X_k).
\end{eqnarray}

Have someone had any idea about the general case?

Answer (score 1):

If $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are $p$- and $q$-forms respectively, and $\{X_i\}$ is a set of $p+q$ vector fields, then the general result is,
$$
(\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2) (X_1, \ldots, X_{p+q}) 
= \frac{1}{p!q!} \sum_{P\in S_{p+q}} \text{sgn}(P)\, \omega_1(X_{P(1)},\ldots,X_{P(p)})\,\omega_2(X_{P(p+1)},\ldots,X_{P(p+q)})\;,
$$
where $S_{p+q}$ is the set of permutations $P$ of $p+q$ integers and sgn$(P)$ is the sign of the permutation.

See for example equation (5.65) in Nakahara's *Geometry, Topology, and Physics*.